# Portable Makevars for R package using C, GSL and OpenMP with help of Rcpp

Tags: c, r, openmp, rcpp, gsl

I am constructing an R package where I have few third party C functions which use GSL and OpenMP, and I then call these from R using wrappers made with Rcpp (which just modify some arguments and call the appropriate C function). Everything works fine in my Windows machine, but I am not sure how to define the Makevars.win and Makevars file in a portable way. My Makevars.win looks like this:

```
## This assumes that the LIB_GSL variable points to working GSL libraries
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS=-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/x64 -lgsl -lgslcblas $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CFLAGS=$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

It is basically copied from various sources. Like said, this compiles in my computer (using toolchain of from Rtools), and if I remove `PKG_CFLAGS=$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)` I can also compile without OpenMP (for some reason I don't understand I get error if I remove OpenMP flag in `PKG_LIBS`).

My Makevars file looks identical, but I don't have access to Unix platforms so I am not sure how to deal with that side. My guess is that I need to replace `LIB_GSL` with something?

## **EDIT:**

Okay, I think I finally understand how configure etc. works and was able to get everything working.

My `Makevars.win`:

```
## This assumes that the LIB_GSL variable points to working GSL libraries
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS="-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/$(R_ARCH)" -lgsl -lgslcblas $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CFLAGS=$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

My `Makevars.in`:

```
GSL_CFLAGS = @GSL_CFLAGS@
GSL_LIBS = @GSL_LIBS@

PKG_LIBS=$(GSL_LIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CFLAGS=$(GSL_CFLAGS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

And my `configure.ac:`

```
AC_INIT([testpackage], 0.0.1)

## Use gsl-config to find arguments for compiler and linker flags
##
## Check for non-standard programs: gsl-config(1)
AC_PATH_PROG([GSL_CONFIG], [gsl-config])
## If gsl-config was found, let's use it
if test "${GSL_CONFIG}" != ""; then
    # Use gsl-config for header and linker arguments
    GSL_CFLAGS=`${GSL_CONFIG} --cflags`
    GSL_LIBS=`${GSL_CONFIG} --libs`
else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([gsl-config not found, is GSL installed?])
fi

# Now substitute these variables in src/Makevars.in to create src/Makevars
AC_SUBST(GSL_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(GSL_LIBS)

AC_OUTPUT(src/Makevars)
```

I then run autoconf in `testpackage` directory in order to get `configure` file, which in turn converts `Makevars.in` to `Makevars` when running `R CMD INSTALL`.

Comment: try a virtual machine with linux

Answer (score 0):

There are a few CRAN packages using the GSL, and/or our RcppGSL bindings.  Here is what I do in one of these (my RcppZiggurat package):

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()"`
```

That is the entire `/src/Makevars`. You can trivially add the same OpenMP variable from R.  This does of course create a dependency on RcppGSL (as I already use it in RcppZiggurat).  Else you can look into the `R/init.R` of RcppGSL and see how it tries to talk to `gsl-config` and store those values.  You can do the same in `src/Makevars` -- it is just basic Make usage and nothing Rcpp specific.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have looked googled more. I now downloaded the sources of RcppZiggurat and RcppGSL from CRAN, and in Makevars of RcppZiggurat there is also `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`. I though Rcpp:::LdFlags is depracated? And In RcppGSL there is no file R/init.R?

Comment: I copied the `configure` and `configure.ac` files from RcppGSLExample and modified `Makevars.in' accordingly. Found a way to test with linux and seemed to work fine.

Comment: Yup, that call can be removed as it is 'empty' now. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Turns out that in the dev version I made that change at the end of July.